# Does an Android Animation stop on its own if made invisible?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
ImageView something = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_animated_image_view);
something.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
((AnimationDrawable)something.getDrawable()).stop(); // <-- Is this line redundant?
```

In my case, i have a bunch of animations of which only one runs/is visible, and right now I'm calling setVisibility() and stop() on all of them. Might get faster if i don't need to call stop() on my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `AnimationDrawable` source:

```
@Override
    public boolean setVisible(boolean visible, boolean restart) {
        boolean changed = super.setVisible(visible, restart);
        if (visible) {
            if (changed || restart) {
                setFrame(0, true, true);
            }
        } else {
            unscheduleSelf(this);
        }
        return changed;
    }
```

So if you apply setVisible(false,false) to the `AnimationDrawable` then the animation will stop. But not when you apply it to the `View`. If you want the animation to go smooth then try AnimationDrawable.setVisible(false,false) and if you want your view Invisible don't make it invisible cause a lot of UI stuff happens then. Try setting an Alpha animation ,make it transparent and setFillAfter(true). When the animations end call view to `setVisibility(View.Invisible)` where is needed. This probably with give you some FPS. But generally consider overall what UI stuff happen when you animate. Avoid GC calls and view invalidations

Comment: Thanks, this is not performance critical in my project but it's always good to save a bit of CPU.